# Sinatra public assets not available when uploading to Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I've just started working on a simple Sinatra app and when uploading it to Heroku. None of the files in the public folder seem to be available but it works fine locally.

Are there any obvious reasons this might be happening?

Right now the code is really simple:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'haml'
require 'rdiscount'

set :static, true
set :public_folder, "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/public"

get '/' do
  haml :landing
end

__END__

@@ layout
%html
  %head
    %meta{charset: "utf-8"}/
    %meta{content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", name: "viewport"}/
    %meta{content: "", name: "description"}/
    %meta{content: "", name: "author"}/
    %title TIL
    %link{href: "http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css", rel: "stylesheet"}
    %link{rel: "stylesheet", href: "/styles.css"}
  %body
  = yield

@@landing
%section.hero
  .container
    .pure-g-r
      .pure-u-1
        .logo
          ...
.container
  %hr/
  .pure-g-r
    .pure-u-2-3
      .padding-box
        :markdown
          ...
    .pure-u-1-3
      .padding-box
        ..
  %hr/
  .pure-g-r
    .pure-u-1
      .padding-box
        :markdown
          ...
  %hr/
  .pure-g-r
    .pure-u-1
      .padding-box
        %h2 ...
    .pure-u-1-3
      .padding-box
        %img.img-rounded{src: "GD-thumbnail.png"}/
        :markdown
          ...
    .pure-u-1-3
      .padding-box
        %img.img-rounded{src: "AL-thumbnail.png"}/
        :markdown
          ...
    .pure-u-1-3
      .padding-box
        %img.img-rounded{src: "BP-thumbnail.png"}/
        :markdown
          ...
  %hr/
  %footer
    .row
      .col-lg-12
        %p
```

Local file structure is:

```
TIL (folder)
- app.rb
- Gemfile
- Procfile
- public (folder)
  - AL-thumbnail.png
  - BP-thumbnail.png
  - GD-thumbnail.png
  - logo.png
  - styles.css
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have modified the `:public_folder` setting? `public` is [already the default for sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html). What does your file structure look like locally?

Comment: I added that in because I thought it might need to explicitly be defined when uploading to Heroku. I also tried renaming public as something else.

Comment: If you try to go to http://*whatever-your-apps-name-is*.herokuapp.com/AL-thumbnail.png or http://*whatever-your-apps-name-is*.herokuapp.com/styles.css, do you get a 404 or do you see the image or CSS? If you go to http://*whatever-your-apps-name-is*.herokuapp.com and view source, what URL is in the `<link rel="stylesheet">`'s `href`?

Comment: It gives a 404 not found. The tag for the stylesheet is `<link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Ok, what about at http://*whatever-your-apps-name-is*.herokuapp.com/public/styles.css ? And are you absolutely positive that you have added the files in your `public` directory to git and you have pushed the commits that added those files to your heroku repository? I know that sounds like I'm asking to make sure your computer is turned on, but please check again for me. If your git remote is named `heroku`, do `git log heroku/master --stat` and confirm that your files are in one of those commits.

Comment: Assets were definitely there as I checked in heroku console. I took someone else's functional sinatra-heroku app and ported across slices of my code until my app was complete and working - still don't know what the original problem was...

Comment: Have a look at my answer (below) - it might b the gem 'rack-flash-session'? If so, then mark this as 'answered'.?

Comment: Sorry, I resorted to starting an existing sinatra/heroku app and copying over the necessary code, so I have no way of testing your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in your Heroku log file:

> heroku logs

If you can see something like

> Rack::Flash::SessionUnavailable - Rack::Flash depends on session middleware.:

Then add

> gem "rack-flash-session"

to you Gemfile.

Also add 'require 'rack/flash/test'' to you main file.

This will force heroku to load the desired middelware.